# Removing duplicates using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I am writing a function that is supposed to count duplicates and mention how many duplicates are of each individual record. For now my output is giving me the total number of duplications, which I don't want.

i.e. if there are 4 duplicates of one record, it's giving me 4 instead of 1; if there are 6 duplicates of 2 individual records it should give me 2.

Could someone please help find the bug?

Thank you

```
def duplicate_count(text):
text = text.lower()
dict = {}
word = 0
if len(text) != "":
    for a in text:
        dict[a] = dict.get(a,0) + 1
    for a in text:
        if dict[a] > 1:                
            word = word + 1
    return word
else:
    return "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
def duplicate_count(text):
text = text.lower()
dict = {}
word = 0
if len(text) != "":
    for a in text:
        dict[a] = dict.get(a,0) + 1
    return sum(1 for a in dict.values() if a >= 2) 
else:
    return "0"
```

Comment: You actually didn't fix it. You broke Python. You just told python that `dict` is now just the one little dictionary that you made, so now `dict` as a keyword has been completely destroyed.

Comment: What if I changed dict to another word

Comment: I corrected my answer. My initial answer was wrong. I misread your question (due to distractions). You can just change the word. I'd still take a look at my new solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `set` and `sum`. First `set` is used to remove all duplicates. This is so we can have as few iterations as possible, as-well-as get an immediate count, as opposed to a "one-at-a-time" count. The `set` is then used to create a dictionary that stores the amount of times a character repeats. Those values are then used as a generator in `sum` to sum all the times that the "repeat value" is greater than 1.

```
def dup_cnt(t:str) -> int:
    if not t: return 0

    t = t.lower()
    d = dict()
    
    for c in set(t): 
        d[c] = t.count(c)

    return sum(v>1 for v in d.values())

print(dup_cnt('aabccdeefggh')) #4
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks good for my next steps. I am still learning and for this assignment I was asked to use a dictionary to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question you asked.
But I assume you want to get the count or details of each letter's duplication in the text. You can do this, hoping this can help.

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    count_dict = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        count_dict[letter] = count_dict.setdefault(letter, 0) + 1
    return count_dict

ret = duplicate_count('asuhvknasiasifjiasjfija')

# Get all letter details
print(ret)
#{'a': 5, 's': 4, 'u': 1, 'h': 1, 'v': 1, 'k': 1, 'n': 1, 'i': 4, 'f': 2, 'j': 3}

# Get all letter count
print(len(ret))
# 10

# Get only the letters appear more than once in the text
dedup = {k: v for k, v in ret.items() if v > 1}

# Get only duplicated letter details
print(dedup)  
# {'a': 5, 's': 4, 'i': 4, 'f': 2, 'j': 3}

# Get only duplicated letter count
print(len(dedup))
# 5
```